# How to fade some character of a textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a Textview with some texts. So if the line count is more than two  i have to fade some  characters at the end of second line.

How can we do something like that?

[image]

Comment: it is specific functional, you can just use `android:ellipsize="end"        android:maxLines="2"`

Comment: @serg3z Thank you for your comment.
It  will add 3 dots at the end which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html font color like that :

```
 String text = textView.getText().toString();

    String a = text.substring(0, text.length()-2);
    String b = text.substring(text.length()-2, text.length()-1);
    String c = text.substring(text.length()-1, text.length());

    text = "<font color=#000000>"+a+"</font><font color=#777777>"+b+"</font>"+"<font color=#AAAAAA>"+c+"</font>";

    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Result screenshot :

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: @Santosh  text.length() is giving the length of complete text . So the above code is not giving expected result for two lines.